# Batch - If not defined a variable

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd

What can I do if I want to echo a warning if the variable `favnum` is not filled?

I already tried this:

```
echo What's your favorite color?
echo.
set /p favnum=">"

if not defined favnum(
goto nope
)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

give it a space between `favnum` and `(`

As you wrote it, `if` checks for a variable named `favnum(`. It then misses a command to execute and spits a syntax error.

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out previously you missed out a space between `favnum` and `(`

You could also use

```
echo What's your favorite color?
echo.
set /p favnum=">"

if "%favnum%"=="" (
goto nope
)
```

or put *is the variable not set* on one line

```
echo What's your favorite color?
echo.
set /p favnum=">"

if "%favnum%"=="" goto nope
```

which would make your example

```
echo What's your favorite color?
echo.
set /p favnum=">"

if not defined favnum goto nope
```